# Decode/Read PDF417 Barcode in python

Tags: python, opencv, barcode, decoder

I'm looking for a good python module to decode/read pdf417 barcodes on drivers licence. My research came up with only the PyZbar which works best for QRcodes and 1D-barcodes and not the PDF417.

I will like to extract information such as:
first name,
last name,
DOB,
Address,
City,
State,
ZipCode,
Height,
Eye Color,
Hair Color,

[Sample Barcode Image from Google:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKMyk.png)

Comment: For better understanding, we need your sample codes. Please, share them with us.

Answer (score 3):

There are two libraries that I know of for decoding PDF417 barcodes.

You can checkout [python-zxing](https://github.com/dlenski/python-zxing) which is a python wrapper for the ZXing decoder or you can use [pdf417decoder](https://github.com/sparkfish/pdf417decoder) which is a native Python port of a [C# PDF417 decoder library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4042463/PDF417-Barcode-Decoder-NET-Class-Library-and-Two-D).

ZXing requires files to be saved to the disk first while pdf417decoder can take a PIL Image object directly.